# Include IE executables in Eclipse RCP project

Tags: internet-explorer, d3.js, eclipse-rcp

I'd like to render [D3 graphs](http://d3js.org/) in my Eclipse RCP application using swt.browser and Internet Explorer 10. Unfortunately due to corporate policies, my client is stuck with IE8 and can't upgrade.

I was wondering if I could include all the necessary IE files in my RCP project so IE10 (and the graphs) would work out of the box for my client without having to upgrade the browser.

Is this possible? Does anyone know how? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, for both licensing and technical reasons, you cannot embed and redistribute IE10 executables. Doing so would violate Microsoft's copyright, and it wouldn't work anyway because IE10 does not support a non-installed "side-by-side" configuration.